# Accessing config.groovy variables from Quartz Job

Tags: grails, configuration-files

This is `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` from which i am trying to access
variables in Quartz Job. This is the variable i am trying to access in the quartz job below:

```
ais.mediquery.TrialVariable="My Variable";
```

Quartz Job :

```
import com.projectname.*;

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication;

import grails.util.Holders
class TrialJob {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication;

    static triggers = {

      simple repeatInterval: 10000l // execute job once in 5 seconds

    }

    def execute() {
        //log.info(grailsApplication.ais.mediquery.TrialVariable)
        println (Holders.config.ais.mediquery.TrialVariable)
    }
}
```

I have tried using both GrailsApplication and `ais.mediquery.TrialVariable`
but none of them seem to access variables and print them

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you getting any error? Where have you defined your config value? PROD? DEV? Whats is the environment you are running your grails-app against?

Comment: In case of grailsApplication I think it should be grailsApplication.config.ais...

Comment: Hi Lalit it is running on localhost:8080 ,hi abdullah i did tried grailsApplication.config.ais.mediquery.TrialVariable.It does'nt give any error but it doesnt print those variables from config..

Comment: Assuming that you are running your application in development environment, Can you check if your config variable is defined properly, i.e. within development { your-config-variable }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config is definitely available from `GrailsApplication` and that's the best option:

```
println grailsApplication.config.ais.mediquery.TrialVariable
```

If that doesn't seem to work, try printing the whole config and see if you have a typo:

```
println grailsApplication.config
```

or

```
println grailsApplication.config.flatten()
```

As with any behavior that seems strange, run `grails clean` and `grails compile` to force a clean compile.

Comment: i did grails clean and grails compile and it works now :) thanks..may be the dependencies were not getting refreshed

Comment: I can access the string variable but if i try accessing a data structure ..for example a list or map from config.groovy it gives me a null initialized map or list ?